# Flat conical hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

What can be said about an isometric immersion $f:\mathbb{R}^3-\left\{0\right\}\to\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\left\|f(x)\right\|=\left\|x\right\|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^3-\left\{0\right\}$?

Comment: That depends on what kind of solutions one is willing to allow.  It's not hard to show that such a map is of the form $f(x) = |x|g(x/|x|)$ for some isometric immersion $g:S^2\to S^3$, and there are many such isometric immersions $g$, especially if one only requires that $g$ be $C^1$.  It is easy to write down $C^1$ examples that are smooth except at two points in $S^2$, but it is not obvious to me whether there is an example that is $C^2$ everywhere on $S^2$ other than the obvious totally geodesic isometric immersions. I imagine that this is known, but I don't recall a reference.

Comment: Interesting. I guess the argument in the paper 'Isometric immersions of constant curvature manifolds' by Ferus uses only $C^2$.

Comment: I don't know Ferus' paper.  I guess you mean that Ferus assumes that the mapping is *at least* $C^2$.  What conclusion does he draw from this?

Comment: @RobertBryant: Exactly. He shows that every isometric immersion of $\mathbb{S}^n$ into $\mathbb{S}^{2n-1}$ is totally geodesic.